# bootstrap 4 text on right is going left

Tags: text

I am trying to have an image and text on the left, using bootstrap 4, and the text "stuff on right" on the right hand side. But currently the text "stuff on right" is next to the image and text on the left:

```
<main role="main" class="container">
   <div class="d-flex  p-3 my-3 text-white-50 rounded box-shadow" style="background:#d5d7f6;">
      <img class="mr-3" src="http://localhost/MVC/app/views/images/bob2.jpg" alt="myTitle" width="48" height="48">
    
      <div class="lh-100">
         <h6 class="mb-0 text-white lh-100">main title</h6>
         <small>a sub heading</small>
      </div>
    
      <div class="text-right">
         <h3>stuff on right</h3>
      </div>
    
   </div>      
</main>
```

Comment: Use `class="text-right"` for "stuff on right"

Comment: sorry still the same